# C# WPF Async Event

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, data-binding

This WPF application needs to pass data from a selection in a UserControl back to the parent Window so the data can be used to populate the other UserControls.  The selection makes a HTTP request to a database, so it needs to be asynchronous.  My current method for passing data from a child UserControl to the parent Window is using a RelayCommand that fires an event.

```
    public RelayCommand<Project> SelectProjectCommand { get; private set; }
    public event Action<Project> SelectProjectRequested = delegate { };


    public ProjectsViewModel()
    {
        SelectProjectCommand = new RelayCommand<Project>(SelectProject);
    }

    private void SelectProject(Project project)
    {
        SelectProjectRequested(project);
    }
```

The Main Window subscribes to the SelectProjectRequested event, and when it fires, executes an asynchronous method that gets data from the database.

```
private async void InitializeSearchView(Project project)
{
    if (project != null)
    {
       await _searchViewModel.GetAllMaterialsForProjectAsync(project);
    }
}

public ViewModel()
{
    _projectsViewModel.SelectProjectRequested += InitializeSearchView;
}
```

I'm trying to follow [asynchronous best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming), and make it asynchronous from top to bottom.  However, I can't figure out how to make events asynchronous.  I can make an asynch RelayCommand, and I can make asynch methods, but how do I connnect the two with an event?  Or is there a better way to connect the data of the UserControl with the data of the Main Window in an asynchronous way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use AsyncRelayCommand? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/asyncrelaycommand

In general, the when you are dealing with UI events, it is acceptable to use also async void (since they do not need to return anything).

However, the idea of passing selected element this way is not a best practice I would suggest to rework that part of your logic. Maybe you should also look into  Messenger for that ? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger)

Comment: This combination seems like it will solve my problem.  IMessenger from Mvvm Toolkit seems very handy for this type  of situation.  However, I can't figure out how to implement an Asynchronous version of it

Comment: Or maybe I can just do this to make it async:
`await Task.Run(()=> WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new SelectProjectMessage(project)));`

Comment: why would you need a Async version of sending Messages is the first place?  This will not provide you any benefits and only complicates the code as well as reduces the overall performance of your application

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why my method is running into problems then.  I assumed it was because I was triggering an Async Void Method() from an event.  So I was trying to make everything async to remove the void.

Comment: async void is bad because you can not catch/handle the exceptions from outside of the scope (it is fire and forget type). Are you sure you have properly connected Event to command?

Comment: I tried to make another post that is more specific
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75723844/async-problems-with-c-sharp-event-actiont-triggering-async-method