# Async Problems with C# event Action<T> triggering Async method

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, async-await

I'm struggling a bit with asynchronous programming.  I want a selection in one viewModel to trigger an asynchronous HttpRequest in another ViewModel.  However, it doesn't seem to be working, and I think its because asynchronous methods are being called by synchronous events.  I know its [best practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) to have async methods from top to bottom.

In the code below, the user makes a selection in the ProjectsView.  This triggers a RelayCommand (maybe this should be async) that triggers an event Action.  The Main ViewModel listens to this event, and passes on the selected Project to the SearchViewModel.  The ViewModel calls an async method in the SearchViewModel, making an HTTP Request.  This is where my code always seems to get stuck waiting.

```cs
public class ProjectsViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public RelayCommand<Project> SelectProjectCommand { get; private set; }
    public event Action<Project> SelectProjectRequested = delegate { };

    public ProjectsViewModel()
    {
       SelectProjectCommand = new RelayCommand<Project>(SelectProject);
    }
    private void SelectProject(Project project)
    {
       SelectProjectRequested(project);
    }
        
}
```

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        _projectsViewModel.SelectProjectRequested += InitializeSearchView;            
    }

    private async void InitializeSearchView(Project project)
    {
       if (project != null)
       {
            await SearchViewModel.GetAllMaterialsForProjectAsync(project);
       }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class SearchViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public async Task GetAllMaterialsForProjectAsync(Project project)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri(HttpClientInstance.BaseUri + "materials/get-materials-for-project/")
        };
        msg.Headers.Add("projectID", $"{project.Id}");
        string responseString = null;
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await HttpClientInstance.httpClient.SendAsync(msg);
            responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            responseString = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        if (responseString != null)
        {
            List<WindowEntity> windows = DeserializeMaterials(responseString);
            Windows = new ObservableCollection<WindowEntity>(windows);
        }                
    }
}
```

At the HTTP Request, there are a couple of threads that are just waiting.  Nothing seems to happen.  Then a get an exception, but it just says "A Task Was Cancelled"

[image]

I'm guessing this has to do with async methods being triggered by a synchronous event Action.  Or perhaps it has to do with async void Methods.  I'm not exactly sure.  Is there a better way to do this?

Someone suggested using the [Mvvm Toolkit's messenger class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger) to communicate between the viewModels, but this actually doesn't compile with my stack.  I get crazy reference issues.

Comment: I think I am doing proper communication/messaging between ViewModels.  I just dont know how to make this asynchronous.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o62iFhXkWS4&list=RDCMUC7X9mQ_XtTYWzr9Tf_NYcIg&index=3

Comment: Side note: you need to dispose the request and response with `using`

Answer (score 1):

You have a deadlock because first `await` blocks return to the UI thread.

I would try change first `await` to:
`await SearchViewModel.GetAllMaterialsForProjectAsync(project).ConfigureAwait(false);`

If that doesn't help, then you need to reorganize your code. This is a very informative [faq article about ConfigureAwait](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/).

Comment: The link you provided suggests not using .ConfigureAwait(false) in a WPF context.  Which I am using WPF, so this might not be the best solution.  
It also suggests that using .ConfigureAwait(false) would need to be used all the way down, and not just at the top level method.

Comment: I'm working in WPF too. `ConfigureAwait(true)` should be used only when, after returning, you want to change a UI. You should avoid changing UI in the logic part of the application. Regarding faq, lets imagine that all logic is a separate library - it should not use `ConfigureAwait(true)`. Here is another page about that: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 0):

I dont even know where to begin with correcting your code. However I will attempt and make a quick solution for you. So we have 3 ViewModel classes:

```
public class ProjectsViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public event Action<TempProject> OnProjectSelectionChanged;
    public ObservableCollection<TempProject> temp { get; set; }

    public ICommand SelectionCommand { get; set; } 
    public ProjectsViewModel()
    {
        SelectionCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(PassSelectedProjectToMain);
        temp= new ObservableCollection<TempProject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            temp.Add(new(i, i.ToString()));
        }
    }

    private void PassSelectedProjectToMain(object? obj)
    {
        if(obj is System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs project)
        {
            OnProjectSelectionChanged(project.AddedItems[0] as TempProject);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a project selection class, that is used as a context in the project view :

```
...
    xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
        <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding temp}">
            <b:Interaction.Triggers>
                <b:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                </b:EventTrigger>
            </b:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListBox>
```

In another (your mainVM) we are pushing subscribing to the event and and executing an awaitable action:

```
   public NavigationViewModel(
        ProjectsViewModel projectView)
    {
        projectView.OnProjectSelectionChanged += ProjectView_OnProjectSelectionChanged;
        
        NavigationOptions.Add(new() { Name = "Project", Description = "This shows how to redirect event into commands", DestinationVM = projectView });
        
    }

    private async void ProjectView_OnProjectSelectionChanged(TempProject obj)
    {
        await Task.Delay(20000);
        MessageBox.Show($"{obj.id}");
    }
```

And this runs async (on another thread) without UI blocking.
If this example does not work for you, please look into your BindableBase and RelayCommand implementation.

**Regardless solution, I would not recommend doing this for many reasons. What I would suggest in your case, is creating a service, that will do the HttpRequesting and notifying the dependable on the information ViewModels**